# automate the process of adding UPGRADE MARKS in each subject based on specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, ssms

I have a table with given values. This is only a sample table, my actual tale contains 15 columns and have more than 1000 rows of data.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_GRACE
(
    SYM NVARCHAR(2),
    ENG NVARCHAR(2),
    MATHS NVARCHAR(2),
    SCIENCE NVARCHAR(2),
    GEO NVARCHAR(2)
);
insert into temp_grace values ('1','28','5','10','5');
insert into temp_grace values ('2','50','25','30','20');
insert into temp_grace values ('3','15','10','25','20');
insert into temp_grace values ('4','90','95','98','90');
insert into temp_grace values ('5','90','88','25','87');
```

In every subject, the pass mark is 30. I have to calculate how much UPGRADE NUMBER should be added to each subject marks to make it 30 then get the sum of such UPGRADE NUMBER `[TTL_UPGRADE]` for every symbol numbers.

I have to add the required UPGRADE NUMBER to the subjects if total UPGRADE NUMBER is less than 60 for every row.

I have made the `SELECT` query for this condition but I have no idea how can I `add/update` those required UPGRADE NUMBER to each subjects.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        SYM, 
        ENG,
        CASE WHEN A.ENG <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.ENG) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.ENG)
        ELSE 100 END AS [UP_ENG]
        ,MATHS 
        ,CASE WHEN A.MATHS <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.MATHS) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.MATHS)
        ELSE 100 END AS [UP_MATHS]
        ,SCIENCE
        ,CASE WHEN A.SCIENCE <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.SCIENCE) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.SCIENCE)
        ELSE 100 END AS [UP_SCIENCE]
        ,GEO
        ,CASE WHEN A.GEO <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.GEO) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.GEO)
        ELSE 100 END AS [UP_GEO]
        ,(
            (CASE WHEN A.ENG <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.ENG) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.ENG)
            ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN A.MATHS <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.MATHS) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.MATHS)
            ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN A.SCIENCE <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.SCIENCE) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.SCIENCE)
            ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN A.GEO <> 'AB' AND TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.GEO) < 30.00  
                THEN 30.00 - TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 2), A.GEO)
            ELSE 0 END)
        ) AS [TTL_UPGRADE]
    FROM [DBO].[TEMP_GRACE] A       
)
SELECT SYM, ENG, UP_ENG, MATHS, UP_MATHS, SCIENCE, UP_SCIENCE, GEO, UP_GEO, TTL_UPGRADE FROM CTE 
WHERE TTL_UPGRADE < 60 AND TTL_UPGRADE > 0 ORDER BY TTL_UPGRADE DESC;
```

Based on the above filter query, I have to add UPGRADE NUMBER to 3 of the `sym` rows. Now how to update such rows?

```
SYM ENG UP_ENG  MATHS   UP_MATHS    SCIENCE UP_SCIENCE  GEO UP_GEO  TTL_UPGRADE
3   15  15.00   10      20.00       25      5.00        20  10.00   50.00
2   50  100.00  25      5.00        30      100.00      20  10.00   15.00
5   90  100.00  88      100.00      25      5.00        87  100.00  5.00
```

In the first row I have to add 15 in ENG, 20 in MATHS, 5 in SCIENCE and 10 in GEO, similarly for second row I have to add 5 in MATHS , 10 in GEO and for third row I have to add 5 in SCIENCE.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using multiple CTE tables. 
In the below query 
table `Marks` calculated required marks if the marks are less than 30 in each subject.
table `Total_Upgrade_Number` calculates total_marks and checks if the upgraded_numbers are less than 60. 
table `Add_upgrade_numbers` add those required UPGRADE NUMBER to each subjects.

**Query**

```
 With Marks as
 (
select SYM,
       TEMP_GRACE.eng,  case when  TEMP_GRACE.eng  <30 then  30 - TEMP_GRACE.eng else 0 end eng_required_marks ,
       TEMP_GRACE.maths, case when  TEMP_GRACE.maths <30 then  30 - TEMP_GRACE.maths else 0 end math_required_marks,
       TEMP_GRACE.SCIENCE, case when  TEMP_GRACE.SCIENCE <30 then  30 - TEMP_GRACE.SCIENCE else 0 end SCIENCE_required_marks ,
       TEMP_GRACE.GEO, case when  TEMP_GRACE.GEO <30 then  30 - TEMP_GRACE.GEO else 0 end GEO_required_marks 
from TEMP_GRACE),
Total_Upgrade_Number As
 ( select SYM, sum(eng_required_marks + math_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + GEO_required_marks) total_marks
   from  Marks
   group by SYM 
   having sum(eng_required_marks + math_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + GEO_required_marks) >  0 and
          sum(eng_required_marks + math_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + SCIENCE_required_marks + GEO_required_marks) < 60

 ),
 Add_upgrade_numbers AS
 ( select marks.*, Total_Upgrade_Number.total_marks
   from marks
   inner join Total_Upgrade_Number on marks.sym = Total_Upgrade_Number.sym
 )
 select SYM, total_marks "total_marks_less_than_60" ,
         eng, eng_required_marks ,
        case when eng >0 and eng < 30 then eng+ eng_required_marks else eng end "English",
        maths,math_required_marks , 
        case when maths >0 and maths <30 then maths+math_required_marks else maths end "math", 
        SCIENCE , SCIENCE_required_marks ,
        case when SCIENCE>0 and SCIENCE <30 then SCIENCE + SCIENCE_required_marks else SCIENCE end "SCIENCE", 
        GEO,GEO_required_marks ,
        case when Geo > 0 and geo < 30 then  GEO+GEO_required_marks else geo end "Geo"       
 from Add_upgrade_numbers
```

**Output**

[image]